# Async is calling callback before last item?

Tags: node.js, callback, async.js

I have an `async.eachSeries()` function which process a list of objects. After the list I want a `res.send()` function so I can send the result back to the frontend.
But I'm getting a

> 'Can't set headers after they are sent'

error on the `res.send()` line, which it's looks that the function is called before the list is completely processed.

```
module.exports.createOrder = function(req,res){
    console.log("CreateOrder");
    var orderDescription = "";
    var payId = new ObjectId(); //create one id, to pay multiple orders at one time    
    var shopList = groupByShop(req.body.cart);
    var orders = [];
    var result = {};
    console.log("before async");
    //the cart is now sorted by shop, now we can make orders for each shop
    async.eachSeries(Object.keys(shopList), function(key, callback){
        console.log("in async");
        var shop = shopList[key];
        console.log("before saveOrder");
        saveOrder(payId, shop, key, req.body, req.user, function(err, newOrder){
            console.log("in saveorder");
            if(err){
                console.log("Err", err);
                callback(err);
            }else{
                console.log("order saved");
                orders.push(newOrder);
                callback();
            }
        })
    }, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("One or more orders are not saved:", err);
            return res.status(400).json(err);
        }else{
            console.log("All orders are processed");
            result = {
                message: 'OK',
                order: {
                    payId: orders[0].payId
                }
            };
            return res.send(200).json(result);
        }       
    })
}
```

What is going wrong here? Currently testing with one object in the '`shopList`', and all log lines are visible in the server console.

When I remove the line, the function is working fine, but, of course, he is not sending any results. I also tried to move the line outside the function, but that cause, of course again, in a empty `result{}` and a sending before the function is done.

Comment: `res.send(200)` is sending a HTML response with the content '200' - what you meant to do was `res.status(200).json(result)` although just `res.json(result)` should work fine.

Comment: @JulianGoacher wow, so simple. Now it's working! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.send(200)` will send a HTML response with content '200' - what you want to do is `res.status(200).json(result)` although `res.json(result)` should also work fine.